# Android - add multiple fragments at runtime from an array

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a simple String array, I want to create multiple dynamic arrays at runtime and pass data from each array item to a new fragment

I want something like this :

```
String[] names = {"frag_first", "frag_second", "frag_third"};
myFragment frag = new myFragment();

for (String name : names) {
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, frag).commit();
   frag.setName = name;
}
```

[image]

how can this be possible ?

Comment: keeps crashing. I think the problem is that I can not duplicate the same object and refer to it !

Comment: the R.id.fragment_container's fragment is always the same fragment. so you should `new Fragment()` every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem you encounter is:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added

You need to move your new Fragment creation into the for loop. As such:

```
String[] names = {"frag_first", "frag_second", "frag_third"};

for (String name : names) {
   myFragment frag = new myFragment();
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, frag).commit();
   frag.setName = name;
}
```

BTW: Capitalize class names.

Comment: this gives only one fragment (last one) at the runtime.I've made sure the container linearlayout is set to vertical orientation but still one fragment is displayed :(

Comment: EDIT : adding the fragments to the parent container made them appear properly in a linear format. Your answer should be declared as the right one. Much thanks :)